# Compute the specificity of a CSS selector

Tags: code-golf, css

Today, your task is to write a program (or a function) that accepts a string and outputs (or returns) four integers.

**Input**

The input string is a [CSS3 selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/), and can contain basically any Unicode character.

**Output**

The output represents the CSS specificity of this selector.

- The first number is always 0 (because it's used for inline styles, and this exercise doesn't apply to inline styles)
- The second number is the number of ids (`#foo`) present in the selector.
- The third number is the number of classes (`.foo`), attributes (`[bar]`) and [pseudo-classes](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#pseudo-classes) present in the selector.
- The fourth number is the number of elements (`biz`)  and [pseudo-elements](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#pseudo-elements) present in the selector.

**Notes:**

- Universal selector (*) isn't counted anywhere
- The pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after` can also be written with a single ":" (legacy notation)
- Input can use the `:not(selector)` pseudo-class. The selector inside doesn't count, even if it contains ids, classes, elements, ...)
- The "bricks" of the selector are separated by combinators (spaces/tabs, `+`, `>`, `~`, ex: `body > div+a ~*`), but they can also be cumulated (ex: `div#foo.bar[baz]:hover::before`)
- You also have to handle [CSS escape sequences](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) ( `\` followed by 1 to 6 hexadecimal numbers, followed by a space), and escaped special characters (`\` followed by any of these: `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ``) properly. Those escapes can be part of any brick of the selector (id, class, etc).
- You don't need to do anything particular if you receive an invalid selector or a CSS4 selector. Don't bother implementing a CSS3 selector validator.
- Here are a few links to learn more about CSS specificiy:

  - CSS-tricks article: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/
  - A tool (incomplete) that counts it: http://specificity.keegan.st/

**Examples**

```
// Universal

*                       => 0,0,0,0

// ID

#id                     => 0,1,0,0

// Class

.class                  => 0,0,1,0

// Attributes

[foo]                   => 0,0,1,0
[foo="bar"]             => 0,0,1,0
[foo~="bar"]            => 0,0,1,0
[foo^="bar"]            => 0,0,1,0
[foo$="bar"]            => 0,0,1,0
[foo*="bar"]            => 0,0,1,0
[foo|="bar"]            => 0,0,1,0
[ foo  =  bar ]         => 0,0,1,0
[foo  =  'bar']         => 0,0,1,0

(NB: brackets [] can contain anything except an unescaped "]")

// Pseudo-classes

:root                   => 0,0,1,0
:nth-child(n)           => 0,0,1,0
:nth-last-child(n)      => 0,0,1,0
:nth-of-type(n)         => 0,0,1,0
:nth-last-of-type(n)    => 0,0,1,0
:first-child            => 0,0,1,0
:last-child             => 0,0,1,0
:first-of-type          => 0,0,1,0
:last-of-type           => 0,0,1,0
:only-child             => 0,0,1,0
:only-of-type           => 0,0,1,0
:empty                  => 0,0,1,0
:link                   => 0,0,1,0
:visited                => 0,0,1,0
:active                 => 0,0,1,0
:hover                  => 0,0,1,0
:focus                  => 0,0,1,0
:target                 => 0,0,1,0
:lang(fr)               => 0,0,1,0
:enabled                => 0,0,1,0
:disabled               => 0,0,1,0
:checked                => 0,0,1,0
:not(selector)          => 0,0,1,0

(NB: the keyword after ":" can be anything except a pseudo-element)


// Elements

body                    => 0,0,0,1

// Pseudo-elements

:before                 => 0,0,0,1
:after                  => 0,0,0,1
::before                => 0,0,0,1
::after                 => 0,0,0,1
::first-line            => 0,0,0,1
::first-letter          => 0,0,0,1

(NB: parenthesis () can contain anything except an unescaped ")" )
```

(to be continued)

If you have questions or need examples or test data, please ask in the comments.

Shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Good luck!

Comment: Please add examples (ideally covering all the quirks in the notes).

Comment: The list of tests looks really good, but some examples that go beyond a single `1` would be great. (Btw, I think this is actually a pretty good challenge, but an exhaustive list of test cases seems vital to make it work well.)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6 <s>453</s> 430 bytes

```
a=>(s){var n=z=[],c=[0,0,0,0],e=s.split(/[\s\+\>\~]+/);return e.forEach((s)=>{n=n.concat(s.replace(/\((.*)\)/,"").split(/(?=\[|::|\.)/))}),n.forEach((s)=>{if(0==s.indexOf("::"))return z.push(s);var n=s.split(/(?=:)/);z=z.concat(n[0].split(/(?=[\#])/)),/before|after/.test(n[1])?z.push(":"+n[1]):n[1]&&z.push(n[1])}),z.forEach((s)=>{/^[a-z]+$/gi.test(s)||"::"==s[0]+s[1]?c[3]++:-1!=":.[".indexOf(s[0])?c[2]++:"#"==s[0]&&c[1]++}),c}
```

**Update:** improved code, now it handles `:not` and `:before`/`:after` selectors better, nevertheless haven't tested CSS escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 226 bytes:

```
lambda s:[0,(c:=(x:=sub('(?<=\:not)\(.*?\)|\\.*?\\\\|(?<=\[).*?(?=\])','',s)).count)('#'),c('.')+c('[')+sub('::|(?:\:after)|(?:\:before)','',x).count(':'),len(findall('^\w+|[\s\>\+,]\w+|::|\:after|:before',x))]
from re import*
```

The test cases included in the link below are derived from the sample selectors in the original question along with the most complex selectors from Code Golf's [own source](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/primary.css?v=332e219cfdd1).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXRbpswFH1evsIik2ynEK3ay4RG@yFAJwMmsWpsZpu0kaL9enYhZEk7A1EksM@5515f24f26PZaff/RmnOdZGfJmqJiyMbpt5CUcULe48R2BcHk@WeSxUo7mpHt5jmjpyzrn/A7DVhKYUiekyynOMQ4tJRuS90pRwleYxqWBG8xfYBHCo9BM44hNM5iVjtu6OW94LU2/CLxPioAEwQkV6QWqmJSEvySvT2c0sxmT9lDmPcDEBuVTqNIL0DzVW10gwxHomm1cZtzwawofzlunUUJSlO8wSGC5aLxn@cwxGtRjdOP99PbUjJrbwGP/5C01jqfApKgYCaYhP8s4C8L@NcFfLOAn@ZwBAQEnUJAQT5KkF4ZGCg4DzwqsdHa@eRj5fZRuReyIopOEqDpbpml68gdW74otMCrhblm8@K3YmbCxxzTAnMEreRxJsMAz8XzpnVHf2qhXr3AQVjhuD8fK504@DPt9YEbfxt02XkvSuyY2XE30Rm1I7Xx7wtXrJATJVbCToPlnpevExg4GrFc8tJpf9pCV8cPBvE4Rl5NxgMNNuRF5qLmwi6HCnaPz@LceRTAArVB10WG4IW2kw4Jhe6sMF59AWPjxiGi4qS@9YQmyRgBsir8LJOvVq0RvUeDL18E0cVb216vwnTEa/D/3x0gQqtIG7ETiknbH@Oqa6UomeOok5je8w/a8ZKD7vAWDR@DqNXW3dOCINhW@k31lCpiyr5xg@DD0TQc2P32hSsPoZeJrNgp5jrDvRQbtUZbP9aP0BPaQPb7ktdwnkQNl1crx2C3oO8tU9vrrAQ5xD4ucigEau16ueE89ol1298s@mmh6wZEwWSjupPycl6guv8nh6rOfwE)